# How do I store array of custom objects in core data?

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data

Core data is still a bit new for me, so I don't quite understand the ins and outs. I understand how to save the basics like Strings, Ints, etc in core data, but I don't quite understand how to save an array of custom objects into core data, or if that is even possible. From my research, my current understanding is I need to set the attribute to Binary Data, and set its identifier to [exercise] (making a fitness application). Unfortunately when I try to pass my array into the managed context, I get an error in my code that reads "Cannot assign value of type '[Exercise]' to type 'Data?'"

```
func save (completion: (_ finished: Bool) -> ()){
    guard let managedContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext else { return }
    let workout = Workout(context: managedContext)

    workout.nameOfWorkout = workoutNameField.text
    workout.exercises = exercises // error appears on this line, both "exercises" are arrays


}
```

I guess my question is, is what I am attempting to do even possible? If so, what steps am I missing? I read somewhere to convert the array into NSData, and change it back when it needs to be accessed, but my concern is that when I try to change it back, it won't work as planned. Sorry for the long winded question, just want to make sure I'm including all details I can think of.

Comment: Yes, it’s possible, but before you work too hard getting it to work, I recommend a different approach: read up on CoreData **relationships**.  You can implement your Exercise class as another CoredData entity, and then use a one-many relationship from Workout to Exercise, rather than using an attribute of type [Exercise].

Answer (score 0):

For storing custom types in CoreData, the fastest way is:

1. making your custom types (`Exercise`) subclass of `NSObject`
2. setting the attribute's type in the core data model to `Transformable`
3. setting the `CustomClass` to `[Exercise]`

So you have to define your `Exercise` class similar to:

```swift
public class Exercise: NSObject {
  let name: String
  let duration: TimeInterval

  init(name: String, duration: TimeInterval) {
    self.name = name
    self.duration = duration
  }
}
```

Then you go to the model definition and set the attribute type and `CustomClass` field:

[CoreData Model Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzTuo.png)

You can now use your save function as:

```swift
func save (completion: (_ finished: Bool) -> ()){
  guard let managedContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext else { return }
  let workout = Workout(context: managedContext)

  workout.nameOfWorkout = workoutNameField.text
  workout.exercises = exercises

}
```

Comment: I believe your solution does not work. Error: unrecognized selector sent to instance